# Freefield/Anechoic Car Recordings

Tags: field-recording, field, cars, car

Does anyone know of any freely available or available to purchase "anechoic/freefield" recordings of a car engine and/or rolling tyre noise at a known speed. Not fully anechoic of course, there can be ground reflections and it is average road vehicles i'm interested in.

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 1):

Boom library did everyday cars out in the desert on a super quiet test track.  They do good work.

http://www.boomlibrary.com/boomlibrary/products/cars

Answer (score 0):

Since this was brought up again I can add this library:

http://www.newsoundlab.com/hybrid-electric-car